# Symbol Replacement in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a map generated by others with data structure like this:

```
x = {"city": "London", "country": "England", "region": "Europe"}
```

I want to manipulate the data in Ruby. So in order to be able to let Ruby understand it's a map, I need to replace all `":"` to `"=>"`. Is there a quick way to accomplish this in one line?

Comment: What you are trying to achieve isn't clear. Is the data in a file? Obviously the line above can't already be Ruby

Comment: It's not; it looks like Python, or maybe some Python-like home-brewed syntax. The OP wants to turn it into Ruby code.

Comment: I too am a bit confused... If it is in a text file, you would obviously do a Find and Replace of : to =>... but that would be to easy. Could you please further explain what you mean?

Comment: He wants to read a data file, and turn lines like that into lines that can be processed using Ruby's eval().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
my_text = 'x = {"city": "London", "country": "England", "region": "Europe"}'

# Replace : with =>
ruby_code = t.gsub(':', '=>')

# Evaluate the string as ruby code
eval ruby_code

# Now you can access the hash

x['city'] # => "London"
```

Comment: Only do this if you're sure that there'll never be colons in either the keys or the values! If there's any possibility of that, use the JSON method Subba Rao suggested.

Comment: Also, be sure that your strings don't contain anything that eval could interpret as ruby interpolation, like '{"don\'t do this": "#{`rm -rf ~`}"}' - that would be bad

Comment: This is very unsafe and fragile. Using "eval" is almost always wrong. Subba Rao's answer is much better.

Comment: While might deceptively work sometimes, this goes against everything I was ever taught. This is dangerous and could explode in your face very easily.

Answer (score 13):

you need to install this gem [json](http://json.rubyforge.org/)

sudo gem install json

```
    require 'json'
    JSON.parse('{"city": "London", "country": "England", "region": "Europe"}')
```

Comment: I really like this answer. Even though it's likely slower than collimarco's (which I also like), it seems to get at the underlying meaning of what's going on here much better. It's very unlikely that the JSON format for maps/hashes will change, so there's no real technical benefit. It just _feels_ nice.

Comment: If anything gets screwy in the input, this way will throw a JSON parse error. The gsub way will, well, it could do pretty much anything! Really great reason to prefer this way.

Answer (score 2):

```
'{"city": "London", "country": "England", "region": "Europe"}'.gsub!(/: /, ' => ')
```

`gsub!` does an in-place global substitution on the string.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, if you wanted to minimize your vulnerability to `#eval` (which is a rational thing to do) is to use `String#scan`:

```
quoted = /"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"/
pairs = '{"city": "London", "country": "England", "region": "Europe"}'.scan(/(#{quoted})\s*:\s*(#{quoted})/)
hash = Hash[ *pairs.flatten.map { |q| eval q } ]
```

We're still using `#eval`, but we know that we're only `#eval`'ing something that looks like a quoted string, so we're safe-ish.
Since ruby strings can contain arbitrary code (through the miracle of interpolation), we're still vulnerable, though:

```
# arbitrary code evaluation
p eval('"one two #{puts %{Give me a three!}; gets.chomp} four"')
```

The safest alternative is to bypass `#eval` entirely, and use a library for unquoting strings that doesn't allow for
interpolation.  The JSON library (as previously mentioned) is a great example of that.  It may seem slower (since it's
not as optimized as `#eval` is), but it's a whole heck of a lot safer.